# Visualising RDF Triples using D3.js and Vue

Tags: html, vue.js, d3.js, visualization, rdf

I found a pretty good [example](https://github.com/Rathachai/d3rdf) online of how to visualize RDF triples using D3. The output looks like this:

[image: RDF visualisation using D3]

I'm trying to recreate the example in Vue, but I'm not succeeding in generating a proper visualization, nor making my nodes draggable. I'm sure I'm missing a couple of important steps in the `mounted` method (I have basic Vue knowledge). My entire code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-rdf-visualization-vue-d3), but I have also added the most important code below. Any help would be very much appreciated. Current output looks like this:

[image]

This is my main code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <svg></svg>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";
import {triplesToGraph} from "@/components/functions/triplesToGraph";

export default {
  mounted() {
    const width = 800;
    const height = 500;
    const triples = [
      {subject:"ex:ThaiLand",   predicate:"ex:hasFood",     object:"ex:TomYumKung"},
      {subject:"ex:TomYumKung",     predicate:"rdf:type",       object:"ex:SpicyFood"},
      {subject:"ex:TomYumKung",     predicate:"ex:includes",    object:"ex:shrimp"},
      {subject:"ex:TomYumKung",     predicate:"ex:includes",    object:"ex:chilly"},
      {subject:"ex:TomYumKung",     predicate:"ex:includes",    object:"ex:lemon"},
      {subject:"ex:lemon",      predicate:"ex:hasTaste",    object:"ex:sour"},
      {subject:"ex:chilly",         predicate:"ex:hasTaste",    object:"ex:spicy"}
    ];

    var graph = triplesToGraph(triples);
    const svg = d3.select("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

    function ticked() {
      var links = svg.selectAll(".link")
          .data(graph.links)
          .enter()
          .append("line")
          .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("stroke-width",1)
      ;//links


      // ==================== Add Link Names =====================
      var linkTexts = svg.selectAll(".link-text")
          .data(graph.links)
          .enter()
          .append("text")
          .attr("class", "link-text")
          .text( function (d) { return d.predicate; })
      ;
      // ==================== Add Link Names =====================
      var nodeTexts = svg.selectAll(".node-text")
          .data(graph.nodes)
          .enter()
          .append("text")
          .attr("class", "node-text")
          .text( function (d) { return d.label; })
      ;

      // ==================== Add Node =====================
      var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
          .data(graph.nodes)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("r",8)
          // .call(force.drag)

      nodes
          .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
          .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; })
      ;

      links
          .attr("x1",   function(d) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr("y1",   function(d) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr("x2",   function(d) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr("y2",   function(d) { return d.target.y; })
      ;

      nodeTexts
          .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x + 12 ; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 3; })
      ;


      linkTexts
          .attr("x", function(d) { return 4 + (d.source.x + d.target.x)/2  ; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return 4 + (d.source.y + d.target.y)/2 ; })
      ;
    }

    var force = d3.forceSimulation(graph.nodes)
        .force("link", d3.forceLink(graph.links).id(d => d.id))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
        .on("tick", ticked);
  },
};
</script>
```

I found this also a very useful link: https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph/2?intent=fork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on here. The major problem is that the version of d3 that the repository is using is d3 v3, while what you import in your repository is d3 v7, so the syntaxes are very different. And then the `links`, `linkTexts`, `nodeTexts`, etc. should be initiated before the `ticked` function. Then, you did mention that the dragging is not working, well that's because you commented the line:

```
// .call(force.drag)
```

But after uncommenting that, somehow `force.drag` is still error, so we need to implement our own draggable (taken from [this example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/sticky-force-layout)):

```
    function dragstart() {
      d3.select(this).classed("fixed", true);
    }

    function clamp(x, lo, hi) {
      return x < lo ? lo : x > hi ? hi : x;
    }

    function dragged(event, d) {
      d.fx = clamp(event.x, 0, width);
      d.fy = clamp(event.y, 0, height);
      force.alpha(1).restart();
    }

    const drag = d3.drag().on("start", dragstart).on("drag", dragged);
```

And then we can uncomment the line I mentioned and pass the `drag` variable:

```
    var nodes = svg
      .selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 8)
      .call(drag);
```

Finally, you can also copy-paste the CSS from the example you provided.

This is the full demo in codesandbox if you want to see it live:

[image: Edit dawn-river-cfctxg]

Comment: thanks for the explanation and the detailed response! Great work!